# Questions incorrectly closed

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

How my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630469/reasons-why-php-closing-tag-should-not-be-omitted is opinion based? Morever the opposite question [Why would one omit the close tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag) is at the same time perfectly valid. Isn't this against the logic?

I am asking for objective reasons. If there is none then I'm not forcing anyone to provide answers or just say "there are none" if one thinks it is valid answer (although I have already provided three sample ones).

I have an impression that moderators who voted to close my question just don't agree that `?>` may have reasons to be put at the end of PHP source.

---

**edit**: I apologize for confusion. Didn't have a clue this question will bring such emotions. For me it seems perfectly valid question, but it already has been closed for almost all possible reasons as "opinion based", "duplicate", "too broad" :). It is not up to me to decide, so do not take my critics too serious. I just love discourses too much (and this is inappropriate on SO) and I usually take a position to undermine everything.

Comment: While SO does have moderators, it was probably not them who closed yourquestion. Yup, just regular, high-rep users.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate is properly the correct action on this, even though the other question is worded differently, the answers cover the same issue in great detail.

Comment: @Tanner OP in the opposite questions asks "Is there another good reason to skip the ending php tag?". Thus what kind of answers are expected? Will reasons to *not to skip* be on-topic in such question? I'm clearly focused on the opposite.

Comment: @doc that question was asked nearly 4 years ago and the climate, with closing, has changed somewhat since then. If it got asked now it would likely get closed for being opinion based, it's just there as a historic question now.

Comment: @Tanner so now it seems the only legit questions on SO are kind of "whats wrong with my noob code". meh EOT.

Comment: @Tanner you've changed your opinion about close reason pretty quick from "duplicate" to "opinion based" ;/.

Comment: that's not even a question

Comment: @SamIam why first one is not a question?

Comment: @doc because you're not asking anything.  You're telling something; and no, `"Are there any other concerns? "` does not count as a question.  Putting a stock "question" at the end of your blog-post does not actually make it a question

Comment: @ doc I don't want to **duplicate** my previous answer, which I thought was pretty clear... But that's just my **opinion**

Comment: @SamIam maybe I should put those points as an answer, but now can not do that, since question is closed. But question for other reasons seems still valid to me. The second question is constructed in the same way (and many other questions on SO), so I don't know why you only accuse mine.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I handled the flag you raised about the question being closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag) - I tend to agree that it's not a duplicate, *for the same reason that it isn't a good argument for keeping your question!*

You seem to be confused as to why a question asking one thing would be allowed, while one asking for the inverse wouldn't. I'll give you a simple example to demonstrate...

> What are the ingredients in Marmite?

That's an answerable question. It may have multiple valid answers, but the *number* of valid answers is finite and quite small.

> What are the ingredients not in Marmite?

Despite being the inverse of the former, this is *not* an answerable question: the number of valid answers is potentially infinite, and definitely quite large.

So please, drop that line of reasoning - there are plenty of good, specific questions that can be inverted to produce terrible, open-ended ones.

What you *should* focus on is [the actual problem you're trying to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), which *hopefully* doesn't consist entirely of you being bored, deciding to build a list of reasons for using closing tags, and getting stuck after the first three.

Comment: With all respect I think it's not the same thing as question about ingredients of Marmite. It's rather like asking for what it's good to use Marmite and for what not. And I am the one who asks for what Marmite is good (or for what closing tag is good). I also provided fourth reason in quesiton, which was marked as duplicate.

Comment: I also see some sort of contradiction in that list of reasons is supposed to be infinite, while you take a notice that I was able to provide only three. Is it really infinite?

Comment: If it's only three, then you didn't really need to ask...

Comment: Well, even if there are only three, self-answered questions are encouraged. Actually I found fourth reason, but I also pointed out that they all fall into two categories - parsing issues and consistency. On the other hand the opposite question could also generate infinite list of reasons for why to omit ending tag. But that list also seems finite. Both questions are valid to me.

Comment: I think your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement is more broad than those two, which I don't consider as drawback! Pitty such questions are no longer accepted (although I don't understand why some of them are being closed why other remain open). Or maybe just some of them are not accepted.

Comment: So vote to close it, if you feel strongly - but you're still not doing what I suggested, which is to focus on the problem *you're* hoping to solve, and let *that* guide your question.

Comment: Read my comment carefuly. I don't consider your question being quite broad as a drawback. The question about closing tag is subproblem of a problem I am trying to solve - to avoid closing PI tag or not. I wouldn't know if I didn't ask for counter-reasons.

Comment: We have an existing question that gives you lots of good reason to *not* close the tag. If you still have doubts about it (illustrated by the reasons you came up with *in favor* of closing it), **then ask about *that!*** I have little doubt such a question would be answered to your satisfaction, whereas by making it open-ended you've had only disappointment. As the doctor said, "don't *do* that!"

Comment: The answer currently gives only single reason to not close the tag and it's considered by many as "not so good reason". You may be mislead by accepted answer, but it focuses on sending headers too early (moreover some of the points are nonsense), what can happen due to many different reasons and "fault" of closing PI tag is only that you can add whitespace after it. I didn't want the questions to cover each other, or start opinion based question, thus I asked only for reasons why closing PI tag may be desired.

Comment: There are 1900+ questions on Stack Overflow about *just that one issue*. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) is the second most-duplicated question on Stack Overflow. I kinda feel like you're transitioning to "but ignoring the inevitable and excruciatingly painful death, are there perhaps good reasons to eat cyanide for breakfast?" - this doesn't strike me as a productive argument.

Comment: So here we are, at "headers already sent issue"... But this is not caused by `?>` tag. It's any output that can be sent before you intent to send headers. Noobs will almost certainly discover this error anyway, but instead of sooner it will be later. They will be left in ignorance for prolonged period of time. They may start to think that it is `?>` which causes problems and is evil, so avoid it at all cost. But they will have no clue that it is actually innocent whitespace, which can be shining somewhere in the source.

Comment: I'm familiar with the issue, @doc - enough to know it's enough of a problem to not suggest anything that might contribute to it to those unprepared to avoid it. Point is, you seem to have a few thoughts about situations in which the closing tag *is* useful *in spite of the risks* - so if you're looking to vet them, that's fine, because that's *not* a fishing expedition. BTW, this is getting long - [you might want to just join me in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: I can't see about what risk you are talking about. If you read error messages and have some experience you know why "headers already sent" is triggered. If you don't know, then you simply ask or google. People who haven't reached this level should not commit code for public use, but learn. I repeat - noob will almost certainly discover this error because any output will generate it and noobs just do not pay atention to order of sending headers before printing output. Mate thanks for good talk, but today I'm off and I go to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your "question" and remove all the parts that are not a question.  You end up with the following.

> ### **Reasons why PHP closing tag should *NOT* be omitted**
>
> Are there any other concerns?

That is both too broad and is opinion based.

It's opinion based because concerns are a kind of opinion.

It's too broad because there is no limit to the things that people can potentially be concerned with.

---

The other example is different.  It identifies a rule that *"Every good practice book and wiki starts with"*.  And asks why the rule exists.  It doesn't suffer from the same problems that your post does because it isn't as open ended.

Since he's asking about a rule that presumably exists, it is plausible to assume that this rule exists for a known reason(or a known collection of reasons), and unlike to your post, valid answers don't include things that the answerer just made up after reading the question.

Comment: How the second one is not open-ended, while mine is? So are there endless possibilities to keep that tag, but finite to not keep it? "Every good practice book" - Isn't it opinion? I am asking for objective reasons. There are thousands of questions like this.

Comment: @doc the second question is **not** asking for all of the reasons to omit the tag.  It's asking about why the **books tell him** to omit it.  It looks like omitting the tag is conventional wisdom in php, and since it's conventional wizdom, the reasons are documented

Comment: If you read that question carefully OP is not asking why. He alread knows and even rates it as not so good reason ("...but nobody offers good reasons"). Then he asks for "another good reason to skip the ending php tag?". There is no consensus in PHP community. Note that word "rule" is in quotes and read some answers in that question (how pityingly some users explain this rule).

Comment: @doc there doesn't have to be a consensus about a topic for it to be known about

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. The topic is known, so?